# Задание по рекурсии PHP

Tags: php, циклы, рекурсия

Дана последовательность, в которой каждое натуральное число k встречается ровно k раз: 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,… По данному натуральному n выведите первые n членов этой последовательности. Попробуйте обойтись только одним циклом.

Я решил это так

```
function recursion($k, $i = 0) {
    if($k === $i) { return; }

    echo (string)$k . "\n";

    recursion($k, ++$i);
}

recursion(4);
```

Подскажите, это правильное решение? Или по условию не так надо

Comment: Решение неправильное. Для последовательности `1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4...` первые 4 члена это `1,2,2,3`. Сравните с выводом вашей функции.

Comment: так и подозревал )) Спасибо!
recursion($k, ++$i); - здесь получается должно быть другое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какая рекурсия? Вы о чем? Чистая математика. Для числа k в последовательности будет `k * (k + 1) / 2` членов

```
$n = 10;

$cur = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
    if ($i > $cur * ($cur + 1) / 2)
        $cur++;
    echo $cur . ' ';
}
```

[SandBox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/282691c8042e25e8913c59d126b6fb6271403f9d)

**Update**

Вариант с рекурсией

```
$n = 10;

function func($cur, $idx, $cnt) {
    if ($idx === 0)
        return;
    if ($cnt === 0) {
        $cur++;
        $cnt = $cur;
    }
    echo $cur . ' ';
    func($cur, $idx - 1, $cnt - 1);
}

func(1, $n, 1);
```

[SandBox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/136c5c68619a7adf9239e101bcf3e5e8b3350317)

Функция `func` принимает три параметра

- `$cur` - текущее выводимое число
- `$idx` - сколько осталось вывести членов
- `$cnt` - сколько осталось вывести текущее число

Comment: Спасибо! Классное решение! Просто задача из раздела рекурсия. Написано что все решать через нее. Вот мудрава

Comment: @ВладИванов Где? `Попробуйте обойтись только одним циклом.`

Comment: да, прошу прощение, в самом задание не пишется http://joxi.ru/p27wLEpcK7q7n2
сама задача одна из двух на рекурсию

Comment: @ВладИванов Обновил ответ

Comment: Думаю это то что надо! Спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Чистая математика.

На практике стоит избавиться от умножение в цикле:

```
function f (int $n) : array {

  $a = [];

  for (
    $i = 0, $j = 1, $k = 0;
    $i < $n;
    $i++, $k = ($k == 0) ? $j++ : $k - 1
  )

    $a [] = $j;

  return $a;
}
```